# offset with CSS vw positionig/sizing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, viewport-units

I am currently trying to make a resume, but I have an issue with a ribbon effect. In order to make it easy to display on multiple devices, I have sized almost everything using `vw` units.

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h3{
  background-color: pink;
  width: 30vw;
  position: relative;
}

h3::after{
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1.5vw solid red;
  border-right: 1vw solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1.5vw;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<h3>This is a title</h3>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s2f2oag1/

My problem is that when I resize my browser window, the little ::after pseudo-element can gain an offset of about 1px in x, y or both.
Here are 2 samples:

Good except for 2nd one:
[image: Good except for 2nd one]

Not a simple one correct:
[image: Not a simple one correct]

I had the same issue on Chrome (v56) and Firefox (v52), and it shows when I want to print the page.

Comment: Just to clarify this is never an issue until you hit print? If that is the case, where are those screenshots taken from? Also, you said *"I **had** the same issue on Chrome (v56) and Firefox (v52)"* what browser are you on now?

Comment: @Zze This appears not only when tying to print. I'm currently testing it on both these browsers

Comment: I still don't have a solution, but I found the reason why it is like that. Seeing how it was so dependent of the viewport width, I thought it was some kind of rounding/cropping and it is.
When I cheked in the computed styles tab of chrome debugger, I saw that border width/height is cropped, but the "bottom" property is not, thus leading to these inconsistencies of the supposedly equal values